# Filtered cascading drop-downs with Infopath *Error*

Tags: infopath, custom-list

I'm getting an error when creating a cascading dropdown filter on Infopath using SharePoint lists.

**THE ISSUE**

When filtering the **Day** field, based on the **Week** field and submitting the record, I get a different value on the list.

After submitting on the example below (figure 1) I get **Monday 18** under the Day column on the List and the same happens with any other records, a different option ends up showing on the SP list.

*Figure 1*

[image]

*Figure 2*

[image]

**Any thoughts??**

**THE PROCESS**

I'm basically trying to filter the Day dropdown based on the Week of the year that the user is selecting.

For that I have two lists:

1. Weeksoftheyear2016

A simple list showing +50 records

[image]

2. Daysbyweekof2016

In this list I have 2 columns:

- Day: text fields
- Weeklookup: Lookup value pointing to the WeeksofYear2016 list.

[image]

On my form the properties for the Week and Day fields are setup like this:

[image]